# How to update the state of new context provider after ajax success

Tags: reactjs

New to React, trying to update the state which is initialized inside the new react context provider, after the API call is success. I am using React 16.3 .

Not able to update the state value, followed documented steps but still failed to achieve.

This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<MyProvider>
  <MyConsumer>
    {context => (
      {context.updateInitialData(this.props)}
    )}
  </MyConsumer>
</MyProvider>
```

js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext();

export const MyConsumer = HeaderContext.Consumer;

export class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
    updateInitialData: this.updateInitialData
  };
  updateInitialData = () => {
    this.setState({data: this.state.data})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          updateInitialData: this.updateInitialData
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that now even if you, correctly set the state using updateInitialData, you are actually calling the function in render which will then call setState triggering a re-render and continuing the cycle. What you need is instead to write the HOC and update the initialData in lifecycle method

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext();

export const MyConsumer = MyContext.Consumer;

export class MyProvider extends Component {
  // you don't need to store handler in state since you are explicitly passing it as a context value
  state = {
    data: null
  };
  updateInitialData = (data) => { // getting data from passed value
    this.setState({data: data})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          updateInitialData: this.updateInitialData
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

HOC:

```
const withContext = (Component) => {
    return class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
           return (
              <MyConsumer>
                  {context => (<Component {...this.props} context={context} />)}
              </MyConsumer>
           )
        }
    }
}
```

and then you would use it like

```
class Consumer extends React.Component {
   componenDidMount() {
      this.props.context.updateInitialData(this.props.data);
   }
   render() {

   }
}

export default withContext(Consumer);
```

and thne

```
<MyProvider>
   <Consumer data={this.props}/>
</MyProvider>
```

Comment: Nice one, worked, if I want to pass same data to multiple components, then I have to wrap all components, with HOC "withContext" component right?

Comment: can you please add a child component inside consumer component and show how we can pass data, for me child component not able to access data.

Comment: I think an improvement to this answer would be to write the HOC like this:

export const withContext = Component => props => (
  < MyContext.Consumer>
    {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you copy-pasted it wrong but you don't update your state with data provided to the handler:

```
updateInitialData = () => {
    this.setState({data: this.state.data}) // ??? its doing nothing
}
```

try:

```
updateInitialData = (data) => {
    this.setState({ data }) 
}
```